# Making graphs in IE under Windows CE 6.0

Tags: windows, internet-explorer

There are a whole lot of graphing APIs, but I haven't been able to find any that work with a device running Windows CE.

The reason I'm asking is because I've been told that we are going to try to develop a user interface for our embedded device that is entirely web based. This is so that we don't have to make one interface for people using the device locally and another for people using the device remotely.

OK, well the version of internet explorer that comes with WinCE 6.0 doesn't seem to support jQuery or canvas or even JavaScript in general (msn.com loads with script errors) which makes things pretty tough.

Maybe I'm missing a Platform builder option? I've got JScript enabled...

If there aren't any compatible APIs, then I don't think we'll have time to make one. In that case, I'm thinking it might be better to just use a (QT based) native app for the touch screen interface and build another website for remote users...but I'm just a developer so who cares what I think?

Answer (score 0):

IE included with Windows CE 6.0 is very limited, I believe it is based on IE 6.0, but JQuery should actually work. Enabling Javascript in PB might not be enough, try enabling XML related packages as well.